# Facebook userscript events

Tags: javascript, facebook, userscripts

This script only works when I move the mouse.  How to arrange for it to always stay activated?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       Corrige Script
// @namespace  www.Thyago.com/corrigebug
// @version    0.1
// @description  Corrigir o bug que nÃ£o permitia marcar codigos
// @include     https://*.facebook.com/*
// @include     https://facebook.com/*
// @include     http://*.facebook.com/*
// @include     http://facebook.com/*
// @author      Thyago RIbeiro (www.fb.com/thyagosr)
// ==/UserScript==

function att(){
var c = document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message_text')[0];
document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message')[0].value = c.value;
console.log(document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message')[0].value);
}

function att2(){
document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('message_text')[0].value;
}

function corrige(){
if(document.getElementsByName("xhpc_message_text")[0]!== undefined){
     var varDivTexto = document.getElementsByName("xhpc_message_text")[0];
     varDivTexto.addEventListener("keypress",att, false);

var c = document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message_text')[0];
document.getElementsByName('xhpc_message')[0].value = c.value;
}

if(document.getElementsByName('message')[0] !== undefined){
     var varDivTexto = document.getElementsByName('message')[0];
     varDivTexto.addEventListener("keypress",att2, false);
document.getElementsByName('message')[0].value = document.getElementsByName('message_text')[0].value;
}

}

document.addEventListener ("mousemove", corrige, true);
```

Comment: I don't speak any Portuguese, but I think the part of your code that says ```document.addEventListener ("mousemove", corrige, true);``` needs to be changed so it doesn't only execute on mousemove.

Comment: What does this script do?  What do you mean by "stay activated"?  What do you want to happen?  When do you want it to happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "always stay activated"?

Comment: this script gets the facebook code that no longer works, I want him to be always on, when pages @ Include.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough, try `setTimeout(...)` (pt: sua questão não é clara o suficiente, tente: `setTimeout(...)`)

Comment: i need change mousemove to other event...

Comment: First edit your question because it is difficult to understand the term "always stay activated", so will understand as you need it to work. Edit your question in more detail as you need it to work. (pt: Primeiro edite a sua pergunta, pois ela está dificil de entender o termo "always stay activated", assim entenderei como você necessita que funcione. Edite a sua pergunta, nos de mais detalhes de como você precisa que funcione.)

Comment: this script is only activated when moving the mouse on facebook, want him to be always on without moving the mouse. Maybe that would change that part.   document.addEventListener ("mousemove", corrige, true);

Comment: edit your question, please details are important.

Comment: just want to change this function to a function that mousemove be activated without mecher the mouse, which event would you use?

Comment: @AbraãoGabriell I understand what you need, the problem is that it is still rather confusing as this may work in several ways, but that's okay, try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17708316/1518921 (pt: eu entendi o que você precisa, o problema é que ainda sim é confuso, pois isto pode funcionar de várias maneiras, mas tudo bem)

Comment: What you sent me does not work it will not be activated automatic.

Comment: I edited my answer, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17707720/facebook-userscript-events/17708316#17708316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[edit]** (fixed code)

Your question is not clear and I do not know exactly what you want, try:

```
//document.addEventListener ("mousemove", corrige, true); --line commented out that only works with the event "timeout"

function autoCorrige(){
  //call the function "correct" - chama a função "corrige"
  corrige();

  //Waiting 1 second to run the code again - 1 segundo de espera para executar novamente o código
  setTimeout(autoCorrige,1000);
}

autoCorrige();//starts the automatic event - inicia o evento automático
```

**[Tips on how to make a good question]**

How to use *SO* (stackoverflow):

First to have a clear and understandable question you should read:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

when you are targeting a comet for a specific user use *"@USERNAME"*

> **pt-br/pt:** Como usar o *SO* (*stackoverflow*):
>
> Primeiramente para se ter uma pergunta clara e compreensível você deve
>   ler:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking
>
> quando você estiver direcionando um cometário para um usuário
>   especifico use o @NOMEDOUSUARIO

Comment: I had forgotten the code, I edited my answer, try now.

Comment: thanks brown i love you, perfect working :D